# cached html pages and dynamic content

Tags: ajax

I have a caching plugin that creates static html pages from my php/mysql driven site.

On the homepage I've a listing of content `<ul><li>content</li></ul>`

I've a drop-wdown (select), that loads different set of content.

Obviously this isn't playing well with caching plugin.

I'm don't have website yet, I'm in the thinking phase and I'm trying to understand what problems I might face... could you help me with this little part I explained above?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean; but you should be able to stop browser caching by adding a random GET variable into the URL. Like time() for example; your browser should see it as a different page.

Comment: Hi, not talking about browser caching but about server side caching. I'm thinking to use ajax technology to overcome this problem.

Comment: I would recommend AJAX. Can you not use a PHP file or trick it into not caching with the htaccess file? Or set html to execute PHP? Anything like that should stop it caching.